# Custom metadata for service stack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm looking to generate custom documentation for a service stack end point.  I'm aware of service stack's api for such a thing but the problem is that I have is a have to build a highly customized meta data page that is different depending on the values that are feed into the request:

\myendpoint\1\metadata
\myendpoint\2\metadata

These two urls would generate to totally different sets of metadata pages.  Part of the data is procedurally generated so that adds to the complexity as well.

So my question is there an easy way to wire in a custom html page for meta for a specific end point?

Thanks in advance,

Sieg

Comment: I should add that I want to do this for a specific end point and not all end points.  The out of the box meta is fine for the other end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the documentation on [modifying ServiceStack's built-in metadata templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-Page#updating-html-and-metadata-page-templates):

The VFS lets you replace built-in ServiceStack templates with your own by simply copying the metadata or HtmlFormat Template files you want to customize and placing them in your Website Directory at:

```
/Templates/HtmlFormat.html        // The auto HtmlFormat template
/Templates/IndexOperations.html   // The /metadata template
/Templates/OperationControl.html  // Individual operation template
```

Which you can customize locally that ServiceStack will pick up and use instead.

#### Using JavaScript to modify links to point to custom pages

As the templates are static html with template placeholders, one approach you could do is to [add additional JavaScript behavior](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Templates/IndexOperations.html#L194) to either add links to custom metadata pages (or modify/remove the existing ones).

Comment: Since I want to do this for only a specific endpoint (the other couple of dozen end points that I have are fine with the default metadata) what would be the best approach?  My understand with the template overrides was that would override all metadata, which I don't really want to do.  I could redirect based on url contents to selectively redirect to another custom page but is there a better way?

Comment: @SiegmundNagel My suggestion was to just use a modified version of `IndexOperations.html` with additional JS to modify (or add/replace) the links on select services to point to different metadata pages that you have entire control over.